# error #import "PGPlugin.h" in phonegap on lion mac

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, cordova

I am new to iphone developing and also in phonegap. Now i want to create iphone app using phonegap. So i installed phonegap in my lion mac. Now i want to run the webview in phonegap so i followed [this link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-%20%20%20webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS). But now i get

```
#import "PGPlugin.h" file not found CDVplugin.h
```

while i am running xcode4.3 in Mac. Please help me to solve the issue and run the webview in phonegap. Thanks in advance. Looking forward your answers.

Comment: If it is PGPlugin change it to CDVPlugin... Anything with PG to CDV... https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Plugin%20Upgrade%20Guide.md#upgrading-older-cordova-plugins-to-150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error - solved it by following the instructions to upgrade PhoneGap plugins at

https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Plugin%20Upgrade%20Guide.md#upgrading-older-cordova-plugins-to-150